# how to make a down arrow disappear when a user scroll down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When a user scrolls down, how can I make the down arrow in the first view disappear?

0

I want to make the down arrow icons disappear when a user scrolls down the page. Although I searched it on another question of stackoverflow, I cannot find a solution. I made jQuery code. I am not sure it is correct or not.

this is the code on fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/92mtjzew/

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
    $('#slideshow .slick').slick({
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 2000,
        dots: true,
    });
});

$(document).ready(() => {
    $('#userReview .slick').slick({
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 8000,
        dots: true,
    });
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(".box").toggle($(this).scrollTop() === 0) || ($(this).scrollTop() > 0)) {
       $('.box').show();
   } else {
       $('.box').hide();
   }
});
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 2000px) {
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(#FBDA61, #FF3CAC);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    color: cornsilk;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}        
h1 {
    font-size: 26pt;
}
button {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
}
html {
    font-family: "helvetica neue", sans-serif;
}

.box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 94%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 1;
    display: fixed
}
.box span {
    display: fixed;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid white;
    border-right: 3px solid white;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    margin: -10px;
    transition: all .3s;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    animation: animate 2s infinite;
}

.box span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: -2;
}
.box span:before {
  content: '';
  color: cornsilk;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  transition: all .3s;
  z-index: -1;
}
.box span:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
.box span:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
}
.box span:nth-child(1) {
    opacity: 0.3;
    z-index: 1;
}
.box span:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: 1;
}
.logo h1 {
    margin: 0px
}
.logo img{
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    padding: 15px 0 0 0;
}
.nav {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAEB;
    text-align: right;
    height: 80px;
    line-height: 70px;
    background-color: black;
}

.menu {
    margin: 0 30px 0 0;
}
.menu a {
    clear: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: cornsilk;
    margin: 0 10px;
    line-height: 70px;
}

span {
    color: #54D17A;
}

label {
    margin: 0 40px 0 0;
    font-size: 26px;
    display: none;
    float: right;
    color: cornsilk;
}
#toggle {
    display: none;
}
#slideshow {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
#slideshow {
    div {
            width: 100%;
            height: 300px;
    img {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tutorial</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 </head>
 <body>
   <div id="header">
    <div class="logo">
    <h1><img src="img/logo.png" widht="473px" height="50px"></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
        <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" />
        <div class="menu">
            <a href="http://joeynamiki.com/" target="_blank">Work</a>
            <a href="about.php">About Us</a>
            <a href="#">Services</a>
            <a href="https://medium.com/@wcgwd1" target="_blank">Blog</a>
            <a href="contact.php"><span>Contact Us</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div><!-- /#header -->
  
    <section id="slideshow">
        <div class="slick">
            <div><img src="img/image1.jpg" width="1274px" height="640px" alt=""></div>
            <div><img src="img/image2.jpg" width="1274px" height="640px" alt=""></div>
            <div><img src="img/image3.jpg" width="1274px" height="640px" alt=""></div>
        </div>
    </section>
  
    <div class="box">
        <span onclick="scrollDown()"></span>
        <span onclick="scrollDown()"></span>
        <span onclick="scrollDown()"></span>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script>
function scrollDown(){
    var businessPage = document.getElementById("businessPage");
    businessPage.scrollIntoView();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$(".box").toggle($(this).scrollTop() === 0)` will always resolve to a truthy value, as `toggle()` returns a jQuery object.  `if (truthy || whatever)` will always be true

Comment: @Taplar Thank you. I will try to modify the code. Also, I will search what the toggle() is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is use full for you... after 100px scroll down the arrow icon will disappear.
In the above mention code, you use the scroll on the body. you can also add this on full document by changing the class on the scroll function.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
    $('#slideshow .slick').slick({
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 2000,
        dots: true,
    });
});

$(document).ready(() => {
    $('#userReview .slick').slick({
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 8000,
        dots: true,
    });
});

// $(window).scroll(function(){
//     if($(".box").toggle($(this).scrollTop() === 0) || ($(this).scrollTop() > 0)) {
//        $('.box').show();
//    } else {
//        $('.box').hide();
//    }
// });

// scroll selector
$('body').scroll(function() {

    // scroll disatance
    if($(this).scrollTop() >= 100){

        $('.box').hide();

    }
    else
    {
    
        $('.box').show();
    
    }    

});
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 2000px) {
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(#FBDA61, #FF3CAC);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    color: cornsilk;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}        
h1 {
    font-size: 26pt;
}
button {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
}
html {
    font-family: "helvetica neue", sans-serif;
}

.box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 94%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 1;
    display: fixed
}
.box span {
    display: fixed;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid white;
    border-right: 3px solid white;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    margin: -10px;
    transition: all .3s;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    animation: animate 2s infinite;
}

.box span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: -2;
}
.box span:before {
  content: '';
  color: cornsilk;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  transition: all .3s;
  z-index: -1;
}
.box span:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
.box span:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
}
.box span:nth-child(1) {
    opacity: 0.3;
    z-index: 1;
}
.box span:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: 1;
}
.logo h1 {
    margin: 0px
}
.logo img{
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    padding: 15px 0 0 0;
}
.nav {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAEB;
    text-align: right;
    height: 80px;
    line-height: 70px;
    background-color: black;
}

.menu {
    margin: 0 30px 0 0;
}
.menu a {
    clear: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: cornsilk;
    margin: 0 10px;
    line-height: 70px;
}

span {
    color: #54D17A;
}

label {
    margin: 0 40px 0 0;
    font-size: 26px;
    display: none;
    float: right;
    color: cornsilk;
}
#toggle {
    display: none;
}
#slideshow {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
#slideshow {
    div {
            width: 100%;
            height: 300px;
    img {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Tutorial</title>
   <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"> -->
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css"> -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.min.css">
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header">
   <div class="logo">
   <!-- <h1><img src="img/logo.png" widht="473px" height="50px"></h1> -->
   </div>
   <div class="nav">
       <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
       <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" />
       <div class="menu">
           <a href="http://joeynamiki.com/" target="_blank">Work</a>
           <a href="about.php">About Us</a>
           <a href="#">Services</a>
           <a href="https://medium.com/@wcgwd1" target="_blank">Blog</a>
           <a href="contact.php"><span>Contact Us</span></a>
       </div>
   </div>
   </div><!-- /#header -->
 
   <section id="slideshow">
       <div class="slick">
           <div>
             <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558981420-bf351ce8e3ca?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" width="1274px" height="640px" alt="">
            </div>
           <div>
             <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558981420-bf351ce8e3ca?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" width="1274px" height="640px" alt="">
            </div>
           <div>
             <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558981420-bf351ce8e3ca?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" width="1274px" height="640px" alt="">
            </div>
       </div>
   </section>
 
   <div class="box">
       <span onclick="scrollDown()"></span>
       <span onclick="scrollDown()"></span>
       <span onclick="scrollDown()"></span>
   </div>
   
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<!-- <!-- <script src="js/main.js"></script> --> -->
<script>
// function scrollDown(){
//    var businessPage = document.getElementById("businessPage");
//    businessPage.scrollIntoView();
// }
</script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Awesome ! It works!!  I think the range of scrolling the page is little bit longer than I expected. So, I modified the value from 100 to 90. If I decrease the number, the duration of the down icons appearing also is reducing, right ?